# suppress 2048 errors in php

Tags: php, error-handling, shutdown, error-reporting

Ok first, I've been googling for almost 40 minutes and I can't find an answer to my specific issue. I understand that its best to fix errors, but that's not the issue here.

what I need to do is make php NOT report 2048 errors. the reason is, I have inherited a site and I need to setup a shutdown function to catch fatal errors and send me a text message. All of that is fine. however the code is constantly throwing 2048 errors and so when my shutdown function hits the last error thrown is always 2048 and not the actual fatal error. I don't need to turn display errors off as that is not the issue. its the back-end processing that I'm concerned with.

I have tested this by turning error reporting off. when i do that, I get the expected result, but that means I can't log other errors on the server. I just want it to ignore 2048 errors, which I believe are E_STRICT. However my error reporting is only set to E_ERROR and I dont think E_STRICT is included in that.

So, how do I make php completely stop reporting 2048 errors, so they dont override my actual fatal error? But keep E_ERROR, so that I can log other errors on the server...

**Edit**

this is solved... sort of:

I still don't know how to properly suppress that error or why error_reporting() affects error_get_last. However, the underlying problem of being able to ignore that error while still logging errors on the server is solved. I just left error reporting turned off completely and added error reporting to my shutdown function to manually write the data to the log file.

here's the code I used for all non fatal errors:

```
        $message="\n[".date('d-M-Y H:i:s',time())."] PHP Notice:  ".$e['message']." in ".$e['file']." on line ".$e['line'];
        $file=dirname(__FILE__) . '/error_log-'.date("m-d-Y").'.txt';
        file_put_contents($file, $message, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

It's not the answer I was looking for, but it solved my problem I'd still be interested in knowing if anyone actually knows how to turn e_strict reporting off so that it doesn't appear in error_get_last().

Peace.

Comment: Have you tried making sure it isn't: **error_reporting( E_ALL & ~E_STRICT);**, for example. Maybe php.ini has an error or is enabling E_STRICT.

Comment: I'm explicitly setting error_reporting( E_ALL ); in the code. and I tried: error_reporting( E_ALL & ~E_STRICT); And error_reporting( E_ALL ^ E_STRICT); and neither of them worked either. they only work for displaying errors and logging them to the server. but not for what gets reported by php in error_get_last

Comment: sorry I meant I'm setting it  error_reporting( E_ERROR ); not e_all

Answer (score 0):

How did you set the error reporting level, if you set to `E_ERROR`, then `E_STRICT` is skipped.

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
```

Comment: that's what I thought, but for whatever reason when I call error_get_last inside my shutdown function it gives me the E_STRICT error instead of the fatal one.

Comment: @Chris `error_get_last` won't be affected by the `error_reporting` setting, you need to check it by `$error['type'] & error_reporting() === 0` to decide whether to ignore the error.

Comment: when I set error_reporting(0) it affects it. so there must be some correlation. I am checking it so that it only sends the text message on a fatal error. BUT, that never happens because the last error is ALWAYS E_STRICT. even if I intentionally set a fatal error, the shutdown function still get estrict as the last error as long as error_reporting is set to anything other than off.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your PHP.ini file with this

```
E_ALL & ~E_STRICT
```

This will display all the error except E_STRICT..

OR

in your PHP file

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
```

for more knowledge visit PHP NET
http://php.net/manual/en/migrating5.errorrep.php

Comment: tried that.. it works for displaying errors on the screen. but error_get_last still registers estrict errors.